# PHPMyAdmin - Insert without PK get a message

Tags: phpmyadmin

In PHPMyAdmin, i tried to insert a rows. In the success message, i noticed this:

`1 rows inserted. [br] Inserted row id: 4047 (Query took 0.0002 seconds.)`

After many tests, i found that in my insert code,i don't have the column with the PK(AUTO_INCREMENT).

I used the following format:

```
INSERT INTO `tblappointment` (`customer_id`,`app_date`,`work_id`) VALUES ('2', '2020-12-14', '2');
```

If i used this with the PK it is fine.

```
INSERT INTO `tblappointment` (`app_id`,`customer_id`,`app_date`,`work_id`) VALUES ('5', '2', '2020-12-14', '2');
```

In another computer, I don't get tis message with the same code.

** UPDATE **

After more reading, it might be with SQL MODE.

In the one it is working fine, i have:

mariadb v10.4.11
`sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

The new one i am getting the message:

mariadb v10.3.27
`sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`